# What are static meshes and sockets?

Tags: modeling, animation, unity

I was looking through the web to help me out with an animation system and came across this [forum](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/21649-creating-first-person-arms-and-weapons-to-merge-or-not-to-merge?50970-Creating-first-person-arms-and-weapons-To-merge-or-not-to-merge=). The game engine I'm going to use is Unity but I'm sure the principles are the same. The 2nd post from the bottom mentions static meshes and attachment sockets. What are static meshes and attachment sockets, and how can I get them in blender? I tried to look them up, but the only results I get are static game objects and socket nodes.

Also, if anyone has any good advice regarding the topic of the forum, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think "Sockets" here refers to empty objects that acts as parent for instances of for example a weapon or a tool. You would create the socket (in one of the hands if this is a revolver, for instance) with a pre-determined rotation or scale and then would only have to instantiate the child without worrying about rotation, scale, etc. The child would be whatever 1-handed tool or weapon you can think of, as long as it fits in the socket

Comment: @Gorgious So I'm assuming sockets are something you create over in unity? Like empty game objects, or are they talking about bones?

Comment: Yup I guess it would be empty game objects. Though if you're using a humanoid entity you would most certainly rig it and use bones to animate it